# nodejs express - mssql - return two record sets in same response

Tags: node.js

I need to run two queries against different servers / databases, merge the result sets and return them in the same response.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const sql = require('mssql')
app.use(cors())

app.get('/api/', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(config_03, (err) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        let sqlRequest = new sql.Request()
        let sqlQuery = "select foo, bar from foobar"
        sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                /*save first response*/
            }
            sql.close()
        })
    })

    sql.connect(config_01, (err) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        let sqlRequest = new sql.Request()
        let sqlQuery = "select foo, bar from foobar"
        sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                /*save second response*/
            }
            sql.close()
        })
    })  

    res.send(/*both responses*/)
})

const config_03 = {
    server: 'server01',
    /**/
}
const config_01 = {
    server: 'server01',
    /**/
}

const webserver = app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('node running')
})
```

With this code the second result set is always empty. What should I change so that both queries run and the result sets are merged and returned together ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
app.get('/api/', (req, res) => {
 var output = [];
 sql.connect(config_03, (err) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err)
    let sqlRequest = new sql.Request()
    let sqlQuery = "select foo, bar from foobar"
    sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            output.push(data);
        }
        sql.close()
    })
})

sql.connect(config_01, (err) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err)
    let sqlRequest = new sql.Request()
    let sqlQuery = "select foo, bar from foobar"
    sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            output.push(data);
        }
        sql.close()
    })
})  

 res.send(output);
})
```